# Highlighting active link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to highlight the active link, it does highlight it but the underline is suddenly removed. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
    $('nav ul li a').each(function () {
        if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            $('a.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#intro" title="Intro">Intro</a></li>
        <li><a href="#what" title="What We Do">What We Do</a></li>
        <li><a href="#how" title="How We Do It">How We Do It</a></li>
        <li><a href="#modus" title="Our Modus Operandi">Our Modus Operandi</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: you need to explain what you are trying to achieve, otherwise no one can figure out what you're doing wrong. Can you please let us know what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yeah..Intro tab seems to be underlined as its active. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @SandeepNayak, I want to highlight the active link.

Comment: @Labanino.. Did you check my answer??

Comment: @Labanino.. Its not working because its not satisfying your `if` condition `str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1`. See **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/2t82wy7s/4/)** Fiddle. I've put 3 `console.log` to check its flow!! You are referring href and with fiddle I don't thing your `href` gets updated with the `fiddle url`

Answer (score 1):

I can say what you are doing wrong!! You are removing active class from `a` tag and then you are adding it to it's `parent` which is `li`. So basically what you need to do is add it back to current `a` and you can do so just by removing `.parent()` before adding `active` class and your updated function will be as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
    $('nav ul li a').each(function () {
        if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            $('a.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is simpler and it does the job:

```
$('nav li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav li a.active').removeClass('active');
    $('a', this).addClass('active');
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/wfa381s9/).